# Array Map? Walk? Something Else?

Tags: php, arrays

Thanks for all the inputs on the last two questions I asked. Slowly but surely, gettin there in terms of learning more. Now this next question has to do with array mapping/walking. I am not sure how to get this to work, but this is what's going on:

I have three arrays, each made up of keys with their own arrays. Each array looks like:

```
$arr1 = array(
    'service3'=>array('price'=>'2.00','transit'=>'3'), 
    'service2'=>array('price'=>'4.00', 'transit'=>'1')
); 

$arr2 = array(
    'service1'=>array('price'=>'6.00','transit'=>'2'), 
    'service2'=>array('price'=>'8.00', 'transit'=>'1')
);

arr3 = array(
    'service3'=>array('price'=>'2.00','transit'=>'3'), 
    'service2'=>array('price'=>'4.00', 'transit'=>'1')
);
```

and so on.

What I want to do is add the services from each of the three arrays with the matching keys. The caveats are that each array may be of a different length, and each may not have the same service (see above array 3 for what I mean).

I was looking for a cleaner way to add the three arrays together without running a bunch of foreach loops or creating temp arrays. It seems like `array_map` with a callback function would be a good way to go, or perhaps even `array_walk`. Just not sure how to proceed, because of the fact that the arrays may not be of the same length or even have the same service keys.

Comment: Perhaps using SPL's [MultipleIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/multipleiterator.construct.php) with MIT_NEED_ANY and MIT_KEYS_ASSOC

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't even know that existed. Thanks, I will see if that can be used here.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @Jack: The expected output would be an array with the sums of all the services from the original arrays as in: `$returnArray = array('service1'=>array('price'=>16.0, 'transit'=>8), 'service2'=>array('price'=>21.0, 'transit'=>12), 'service3'=>array('price'=>11.0, 'transit'=>8))`

Comment: @MarkBaker `MultipleIterator` only works if all arrays have the same keys and the keys are in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick function, you can use (untested):

```
<?php
function group_by_service() {
  $return = array();
  $arrays = func_get_args();
  foreach($arrays as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $service => $props) {
      if (!array_key_exists($service, $return)) {
        $return[$service] = $props;
      } else {
        $return[$service]['price'] += $props['price'];
        $return[$service]['transit'] += $props['transit'];
      }
    }
  }
  return $return;
}
```

You can, then, use this function like this:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(
    'service3'=>array('price'=>'2.00','transit'=>'3'), 
    'service2'=>array('price'=>'4.00', 'transit'=>'1')
); 

$arr2 = array(
    'service1'=>array('price'=>'6.00','transit'=>'2'), 
    'service2'=>array('price'=>'8.00', 'transit'=>'1')
);

arr3 = array(
    'service3'=>array('price'=>'2.00','transit'=>'3'), 
    'service2'=>array('price'=>'4.00', 'transit'=>'1')
);

$grouped = group_by_service($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
print_r($grouped);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is almost exactly like what I have right now, in terms of creating a temp array and using foreach loops. I was wondering if there was a more efficient/cleaner way of doing this same thing using one of the built-in php functions like `array_walk` or `array_map`. But at least this gives me confidence that my original way seems to be the one to go with! :)